# How to represent the Type of any Subclass of an Abstract class in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Assuming

```
abstract class A {};
class B extends A {};
class C extends A {};
```

I want to accept as a parameter any Subclass of A.

```
function foo(Subclass: A){
   const obj = new Subclass();
}
```

This wont work. I get the error

> This expression is not constructable.   Type 'BaseController' has no
>   construct signatures.

Then I tried

```
function foo(Subclass: typeof A){   
   const obj = new Subclass();
}
```

Now I get the error

> Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.ts(2511)

Because it is assuming that I am passing A and not a subclass of A.

Is it achievable? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3ggvgNwIBQKaGAQggKYAeENAdgCYbZ5FmroIDCtBszZZcBQiRIAzAK5N4ASwD2TBFKVKAFGBkhy6AFwImNAO4JNASgQBeAHxZrOEgiQrICJSABWt42YQdPR4wKwl8SXUtSktiAHo4zwBrYABPaQ1NPliEBOS0jK1MHLyaKCglKAAaUQUMUEgYeCA)?  I'm not sure why you are writing `new A()` in your example code, since `A` is always the abstract constructor and not anything you've passed in.  Perhaps you mean `new Subclass()`?

Comment: my bad. It is `new Subclass()`

Comment: If you are passing a known class to `foo`, is there a reason you don't just construct that class?

Comment: @jcalz it worked.

Comment: @Leon it is not known. In my specific case it could be any `Controller`. and A is a `BaseController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should change the annotation to the following:

```
function foo(subclass: new () => A) {
  const obj = new subclass();
}
```

Here, we are saying that `subclass` is [`new`able](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable) (i.e., it's a constructor function you call with the `new` operator), takes no arguments, and constructs a value whose type is assignable to `A`.  This should accept any concrete subclass of `A` as long as it has a no-arg constructor:

```
foo(B); // okay
foo(C); // okay
```

It won't accept `A` itself, because an abstract class constructor is not considered `new`able:

```
foo(A); // error, A is abstract
```

---

Oh, as a note for people making example TypeScript code for Stack Overflow questions: Note that TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing).  With the example definitions you gave, instances of `A`, `B`, and `C` are considered the same, [empty](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) type.    And [all objects are assignable to the empty type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces), so this also works:

```
foo(Date); // okay also
```

To prevent that, you should add properties to `A`, `B`, and/or `C` to distinguish them structurally, such as:

```
abstract class A {
  a = "A"
};
class B extends A {
  b = "B"
};
class C extends A {
  c = "C"
};
```

Which will result in more expected behavior:

```
foo(B); // okay
foo(C); // okay
foo(A); // error, A is abstract
foo(Date); // error, 'a' is missing
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAQWAQF4EAiTcvAXwG48U0MAhBAUwA8J2A7AEwzZ8hEKQotq9RqnQIAwh259BWXASTjy8qQzwAzAK694ASwD2vBPvPmAFGEMgm6AFwJe7AO4I7ASlIAPiwAkSRLSARzEAArcU8fR2dZMH8GGjwDWzsWPzoEAHoCqIBrYABPLPt5PMLi8zLKm3tMWqKOKChzKAAaNVMMUEgYeCq7ABFgHjbi9k7uvoByYEWEAYQAWwGwU14AcwQgA)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to refer to the class by it's constructor reference.

```
abstract class A {};
class B extends A {};
class C extends A {};

function foo(Subclass: new () => A) {   
   const obj = new Subclass();
}
```

In this case you can pass both `B` and `C` to `foo` since they have constructors. `A` will not be accepted since there is no constructor on an abstract class.